# HTML5 audio only use ear speaker on responsive website

Tags: browser, html5-audio, smartphone

is there a way to tell a browser that all Sounds on my Website should be played over the normal ear speaker on smartphones?

The Soundfiles on the Website can contain personal information and user of my site should be able to listen to the Audiofiles in public spaces.